# A question on surjectivity of a morphism of torsion groups.

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two abelian groups and $f:A\to B$ a morphism.

Let $f_{\text{tors}}:A_{\text{tors}}\to B_{\text{tors}}$ be the induced morphism on the torsion subgroups.

Is it true that if $(B/\text{Im}f)_{\text{tors}}=0$ then $f_{\text{tors}}$ is surjective?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider a surjective homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$, where $A$ is torsionfree and $B$ is torsion.

Simple example: the canonical projection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.